# Limit the list with max 5 digits per number in the list

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I am using a regex for allowing only valid numeric list i.e. 123, 456, 12, 123456789, 12

And this regex is working fine for this. Now I just want that max one can input 5 digit number in the list like

12,34,12345,12 - correct

12,123,123456,1234 - incorrect because this list contains a number more than 5 digits.

```
^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*$
```

Right now I am using this upper regex. Can anyone modify this regex so it will give solution to my question?
( Only regex for javascript please)

Comment: `[0-9]{6,}` with that you can match 6 or more digits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `+` which means "one or more characters", use [curly braces](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/oracle-regular-expressions/0596006012/re13.html) to specify a specific number of characters:

```
^[0-9]{1,5}(,[0-9]{1,5})*$
```

Answer (score 0):

`\d` for Numbers， shorter regex

```
^\d{1,5}$
```

Comment: Yeah this is also right, but some browser engines didn't recognise \d. So better to put number like [0-9]

Comment: Oh, It's nice to learn something new